# javascript: insert script tag inside div and execute it

Tags: javascript

I have

```
<div id=test>
<div>
```

I am trying to insert script

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
s.value = 'alert(1)';
document.getElementById('test').appendChild(s);
```

But after this i find only

```
<div id="test">
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>
</div>
```

Its not running alert(1)

How to do this?

Comment: You need to set the innerText, not the value. As if you had written the alert() inside the `<script>` tag yourself.

Comment: The issue is because you append the child to the div not the script. I think you may need to tell the script to run too. Wrap it in a self executing function or a function that you can then call. Oh - Jeremy has helped you out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use :

```
s.innerText = 'alert(1)';
```

Comment: also can you tell me how to do it using jquery